# What is the best practice when it comes to managing updates to logback.xml for a containerized app?

Tags: logging, containers, logback, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We use logback as the logging framework and we generally set the logging level to ERROR for apps running in production. Occasionally, we need to update the logback.xml to do troubleshooting. 
For apps that are running in a container on ECS, what's the best way to update the logging level at runtime? Currently, we mount a EFS volume on each container where our logback.xml resides.

Comment: Are you using ECS-EC2 or ECS-Fargate? If using Fargate, make sure EFS is supported in Fargate. As far as I know, Fargate doesn't allow EFS mount.

Comment: Exactly! Fargate doesn't support it but we'd like to start using it and this particular issue is what's preventing us at the moment.

Comment: One option is passing the LOG_LEVEL as environment variable. When you start the ECS task the new values will take effect.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment